# php echo inside of include workaround?

Tags: php

The Question:

How do you include a page, who's location is based on a variable?

---

The Goal:

Set Variables (theme location) in a settings.php file...

Root index, should reflect the index depending on the settings.php variable

---

Thanks For The Help Guys!

-Andrew

---

```
<!----//settings.php//---->
<?php 
$siteurl = "http://www.example.com/"
$themefolder = "theme/"; 
$theme = "theme1/"
?>

<!----//index.php//---->
<?php include("settings.php"); ?>

//how do you $E = echo settings variables?
<?php include(" $E index.php"); ?>
```

---

Any ideas for a work around?

---

I want to achieve...
 include(" $E index.php"); ?> = http://www.example.com/theme/theme1/index.php

Comment: perhaps you need to be a little more clear

Comment: You should clarify your question by the way.

Comment: Please use [**example.com**](http://www.example.com) for example domains, since that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically want to include http://www.website.com/theme/theme1/index.php?

That is easy:

```
<?php
include($siteurl . $themefolder . $theme . "index.php");
?>
```

I think that it would be easier to think about this if we knew what do you want to achieve. Include different pages according to the url?

Comment: Just edited question, but yes I want to include that url... Will try your solution in a min thanks!

Comment: including urls makes no sense

Comment: He did not ask whether it makes sense or not but how can he do it. If you read my answer you may realize that I don't think this is the good approach.

Comment: You can ask it yourself. It can make your answer helpful thing, not just a source of some useless "reputation" points.

Comment: Your assumption is not valid by the way.

Comment: @edem I agree with you. However, you're missing a closing ')' parentheses.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - why doesn't this make sense, what is a better practice? I'm open to your answers if you would like to help. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. And by the way you may rethink your whole application as Col. Shrapnel suggested above.

Comment: @user this is fairly simple. `include` is used to include **PHP code**. But there is **no PHP code** when you call this file via HTTP. Therefore, including urls makes no sense

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I thought the "php code" I was using were the variables itself or the path leading to the themes index file??

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a simple solution... Were I could edit a file from "theme1" to "theme2" and then be able to call that file located in a different folder than root...

Comment: @Andrew you said that. **folder**, not URL. if you want to include a **file** from some folder, you have to include a file, not URL. instead of variables think of the PHP code in the **index.php**

Comment: I agree with that. I already wrote in one of my other answers that it is not optimal to include urls if you have the file on your filesystem than you could use a relative path for example. The original question did not include that the file in question is on the local filesystem.

Comment: @ The Col. Im sorry for the confusion see... it reall doesnt matter wether url or path i was just looking for the proper syntax... $SETTINGS["path"] = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/'; is the same as $siteurl = "h-ttp://localhost/example/" i was simple looking on how to include a variable wether it is url or path. i know this is bad practice... but its all i got to work with till im more comfortable with mysql

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file, you have access to all the variables in scope already, just like it is 1 big file. No need to do weird things there.

So if you have this in your settings.php:

```
$themefolder = "theme/";
```

Than you can echo it like this:

```
!----//index.php//---->
<?php 
include("settings.php");

//echo theme folder
echo $themefolder; // will display "theme/"
```

Comment: Good on you for explaining the 'why' behind the 'how'.  OP: remember, you need to include the files before you try to access their variables.  I know it sounds obvious, but just remember that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is really supposed to be done with a database, not a PHP script.

Comment: i would love to learn how to do this thru mysql... but i have to start somewhere and this will be a temporary solution... thanks for your input!

Comment: also if you would like to point me in the right direction to accomplish this particular task i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: user1180159, mysql with PHP is actually fairly simple, however you can make it as complicated as you wish. It is well worth the time learning. My first experience was creating a login form - that was heaps of fun!

Comment: This seems to be a good howto:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Basic-Login-Script-in-PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$themefolder.$theme."index.php" ?>
```